# Facebook v2.4 hashtag Search Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I had been searching a lot for facebook hashtag search. I used the following code for the call.

```
new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/{%23test-981838585181348}",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("graphresponseeeeee", ""+response);
                        }
                    }
                ).executeAsync();
```

The response I am getting is :

```
{Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {#test-981838585181348}}}
```

Please help me out with the solution.

Comment: It just means {%23test-981838585181348} is not recognized. . . you may try "/me" instead

Comment: If we use /me, then in response you will get only get login user id as well as his name. No hash tag will be searched.

My question is if I want to search #happy, in my logged in account by using the above code, then what will be the exact code for this solution?